# Why duplicate an answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

I've seen posts which have the same answers repeated over 5 times.

I could understand if another person posted the same answer while you were posting yours, but sometimes the difference between an answer and the other is small enough to see that other person already gave that answer and it's not necessary to duplicate.

Why do people duplicate another answer?

Comment: Crap like this annoys me... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619682/java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-i-am-inside-the-constructor-of-a-managed-bea/3619802#3619802

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably just because it's an easy way to get some reputation, especially if the answer is short.

Also, I don't believe that the "other answers" popup comes up immediately.

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes 5 people do type their answers in parallel and all click save more or less at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

If you answer identically with a keyword difference, and then you downvote other answers, then you're more likely to score reputation.