# Related posts got related by being duplicates?

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, related-questions

I just remarked this here: [Exact times of answer posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100562/exact-times-of-answer-posts/100563#100563). The question got closed as duplicate. Looking at the **Related** list shortly after, most of the posts there are either duplicates, or speak about duplicates:

- [Should I ask questions I already know the answer to and answer them myself?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/should-i-ask-questions-i-already-know-the-answer-to-and-answer-them-myself) (closed as duplicate)
- [Why duplicate an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43898/why-duplicate-an-answer) (about duplicates)
- [Prevent duplicate answer posts to the same question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49554/prevent-duplicate-answer-posts-to-the-same-question) (about duplicates)
- [Double answer upon single post (with browser history included)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54680/double-answer-upon-single-post-with-browser-history-included) (about duplicates)
- [Should I delete my answer if an earlier one is edited to include the same information as mine?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54568/should-i-delete-my-answer-if-an-earlier-one-is-edited-to-include-the-same-informa) (about duplicates)
- [Other sites stealing content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62178/other-sites-stealing-content) (closed as duplicate)
- [Stack Overflow punishment for duplication is too harsh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65253/stack-overflow-punishment-for-duplication-is-too-harsh) (about duplicates, at least by title)

I think the algorithm which searches related questions should exclude the text `Possible duplicate` for the comparison.

Comment: Those questions are related to the original post *because the original post has the [duplicate-answers] tag on it*, not because it is identifying "Possible Duplicate" as similar text.

Comment: Ah, good point. I think I can close this question, then.